# How to use emmet with copy & paste

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, bootstrap-4, emmet

If I have a emmet snippet like this one:

```
.row>.col>(.row>.col.bg-sucess>br*2)+(.row>.col.bg-danger>br)+(.row>.col.bg-warning*3)
```

and I copy & paste this from anywhere into my vscode, it does not get detected as emmet snippet.

So I usually have to write it by myself so that emmet detects it.

Is it somehow possible to get VSCode to detect the snippet as emmet after pasting it in my file?

Comment: I delete the last character and type it again

Comment: @rioV8 that does not work always, e.g. in the case I wrote above, when the last char is a ")" it does not work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the cursor at the end of Emmet abbreviation and do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> keyboard combination.

Comment: That did the trick, thanks!